# display product quantity in any page or post by shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the product quantity by using the shortcode

```
// display product stock quantity open
if( !function_exists('show_specific_product_quantity') ) {

function show_specific_product_quantity( $atts ) {

    // Shortcode Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '', // Product ID argument
        ),
        $atts,
        'product_qty'
    );

    if( empty($atts['id'])) return;

    $stock_quantity = 0;

    $product_obj = wc_get_product (intval( $atts['id'] ) );
    $stock_quantity = $product_obj->get_stock_quantity();

    if( $stock_quantity > 0 ) return $stock_quantity;

}

add_shortcode( 'product_qty', 'show_specific_product_quantity' );

}// display product stock quantity close
```

Comment: explain your issue in detail for better understanding

Comment: Please explain what your issue is. What happens when you run that code? Error messages? Wrong result? Server catches fire? Btw, are you using woocommerce?

Comment: when I run the code Product quantity not showing... yea I'm useing woocommerce

Comment: I need to Display product quantity in any page or post. I assume you to give me correct codes

Comment: Shortcode function is correctly returning value. How did you use `product_qty` shortcode? Can you give us example?

Comment: I like this use product_qty shortcode <?php echo do_shortcode( '[product_qty id="33222"]' ); ?>

Comment: Thank you everyone.. code is working now

Comment: Can you post the solution? Maybe you can help other users by posting your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check if function show_specific_product_quantity exists or not.
if ( ! function_exists( 'show_specific_product_quantity' ) ) {

    /**
     * Return product stock quantity.
     *
     * @param  array $atts Shortcode attritube.
     * @return int         Number of stock for the particular product ID.
     */
    function show_specific_product_quantity( $atts ) {

        // Shortcode Attributes.
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'id' => '', // Product ID argument.
            ),
            $atts,
            'product_qty'
        );

        if ( empty( $atts['id'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $stock_quantity = 0;

        // Check if pass Product ID is valid WooCommerce product.
        if ( 'product' !== get_post( $atts['id'] )->post_type ) {
            return 'Kindly check product ID';
        }

        $product_obj = wc_get_product( intval( $atts['id'] ) );

        // Check if Manage stock is enable or not.
        if ( $product_obj->get_manage_stock() ) {
            $stock_quantity = $product_obj->get_stock_quantity();
        } else {
            return 'Manage stock not available for this product.';
        }

        if ( $stock_quantity > 0 ) {
            return $stock_quantity;
        } else {
            return 'No stock available.';
            ;
        }

    }
}

// Add Shortcode to get product quantity
// i.e. [product_qty id="{product_id_number}"].
add_shortcode( 'product_qty', 'show_specific_product_quantity' );
```

Need to check few more thing i.e.
 1. If it is a valid product ID been passed or not.
 2. Then if the manage stock is enabled for the Product.